# Determining if a group in legend is selected, using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, c++

How can I determine in code (python or c++) whether a group in legend is selected or not?

```
mQGisIface->legendInterface()->selectedLayers()
```

gives me only selected layers and no groups, and in `QgsLegendInterface` I doesn't find anything about it.

I use QGIS Version 2.14.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `QgsLayerTreeView` (accessible from the `iface` object) for that. I didn't find a direct way (`QgsLayerTreeGroup` doesn't seem to have a method for that), but you can simply reuse the following function:

```
def isMyGroupSelected( groupName ):
    myGroup = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup( groupName )        
    return myGroup in iface.layerTreeView().selectedNodes()

print isMyGroupSelected( 'my group name' )
```

Note that `iface.layerTreeView().selectedNodes()` gives you a list of selected nodes in the legend, which you could use directly, depending on your use case (e.g., print names of selected groups).

---

**EDIT:**
For reference, this is the C++ code that you told me you ended up using:

```
QList<QgsLayerTreeNode *> selNodes= mQGisIface->layerTreeView()->selectedNodes(true);
for (int i=0;i<selNodes.count();i++) { 
    QgsLayerTreeNode * selNode=selNodes.at(i);       
    if(selNode->nodeType==QgsLayerTreeNode::NodeType::NodeGr‌​oup) {
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have to use the `QgsLayerTreeView`. In c++ it is so: `QList<QgsLayerTreeNode *> selNodes= mQGisIface->layerTreeView()->selectedNodes(true);for (int i=0;i<selNodes.count();i++)
   {
    QgsLayerTreeNode * selNode=selNodes.at(i);
    if(selNode->nodeType==QgsLayerTreeNode::NodeType::NodeGroup)
    {...`  Thank you a lot!

Comment: I don't think that's *another* answer @Joseph. I've updated my answer with schmiddor's code for reference.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - Fair point and nice one!