# Programmatically select a GROUP node using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, group-layer

I have seen ways to programmatically select a current layer using `QgsLayerTreeView().setCurrentLayer()` but I cannot find a way to change the group selection. Does anyone have any tricks/hacks that I can use or point me to the relevant `Qgs` class that I can use?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Determining if a group in legend is selected, using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211470/determining-if-a-group-in-legend-is-selected-using-pyqgis)

Answer (score 5):

The following script selects a node by name.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *

def select(name):
    view = iface.layerTreeView()
    m = view.model()
    
    listIndexes = m.match(m.index(0, 0), Qt.DisplayRole, name, Qt.MatchFixedString)
        
    if listIndexes:
        i = listIndexes[0]
        view.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(i, QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)
    else:
        raise Exception(f"'{name}' not found")
    
select("group1")
```

There are also [different type of matches](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum) that can be used when searching nodes.

Limitation: It selects any kind of node (group or layer) at top-level, which means it doesn't select nodes in nested sublevels.

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to search inside nested levels as well.

Comment: @ar-siddiqui I coded a little script. It may help. -> https://github.com/kadirsahbaz/SUHULET

Comment: Thanks a lot. Once we have the group we want to set as current/active. How can we do that? I already have the group, I am struggling with making the group current/active.
I tried the `select` function in your answer. That worked, but as you have mentioned not for the nested groups and I do have nested groups. I wish QGIS had `iface.setActiveGroup()` as that is all I need.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my first comment, when I said "search" I didn't mean just searching like `iface.findGroup()` but searching in your `select` function so that it can be selected as well.